# Simultaneous access to files. Strange locking behavior

Tags: c, linux, file, locking

I can't understand my program behavior.

```
int MyOpenWrite(char *name,int flags) {
    int fd;
       unsigned long tm;
    unsigned long t;

    tm=time(0)+5;  //5 seconds
    for (;;) {
        fd = open(name,flags,S_IREAD|S_IWRITE|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH);
        if (fd>0) break;
        if (time(0)>=tm) return -1;
    } 
    //1111111111111111111
    LockFile(fd);
        DelayInSeconds(60);
    //2222222222222222222222
    return fd;
}

int LockFile(int fd) //return 0 - OK; -1 - Error
{
    struct flock    lock;

    lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    lock.l_start = 0;
    lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    lock.l_len = 0;
    return fcntl(fd,F_SETLKW,&lock);
}
```

This is cgi-bin program.
I've started one request which appends data to some file.
As you see it delays for 60 seconds after lock.
Then I've recompiled the program without this delay
and did the next request.
The second program is waiting between //1111 and //22222
until first program exits.
I expected that second program returns in MyOpenWrite with -1 code after 5 seconds of waiting.
But there is no delay on opening cycle.
But there is a long delay in LockFile.
Whats wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: First "program" does not unlock the file until it quits?

Comment: The first program unlocks the file after 60 seconds delay and then exits. Second program does not run DelayInSeconds subroutine, It has delay in LockFile subroutine for unknown reason,and it opens locked file with fd>0.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have replaced the old executable file with the new version, and that the web server doesn't do some strange caching? I would add some printouts to the two versions of the program to check this.

Comment: I have certainly used printf to show the performance.I am sure that second program was compiled without 60 sec delay. The main thing I wonder is that second program opens locked file with fd>0.

Comment: It might be a good idea to actually check the return code of `LockFile()` since you go to all the trouble of returning it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you're using *advisory locking*, i.e. the file is not physically blocked from being opened but instead it will coordinate readers and writers via `fcntl()`.

Both versions of your code use the same code for `LockFile()`, which means that the second will wait for the first; the `open()` call is not likely to fail unless the file doesn't exist or can't be opened for reading and writing.

If you do not want to wait when a file is already locked you should use `F_SETLK` instead of `F_SETLKW`. That will return `-1` immediately if a lock could not be obtained.

Comment: Nevertheless  locking works. Other instances of program can't access the locked file. Maybe let it be as is? It what I need. I am just afraid that second program will wait forever if something happen with the first instance of program, which locked the file. I just tried to avoid hang by exiting second program after 5 seconds if it can't open the file. I don't know typical solution of locking files. Thank you for advice.

Comment: @nms The `open()` call will always work, that's the whole point; if you choose not to use advisory locking another process can write to the file without a problem. To avoid blocking you need `F_SETLK` instead of `F_SETLKW`.

Comment: I need blocking. Only one process should own the file. It seems nothing dangerous if another process opens the file. It can't write or read anyway. So it looks that F_SETLKW with waiting works good in my case. Or do you prefer F_SETLK for some reason? Thank you.

Comment: @nms You should use SETLK only if you want to know immediately whether the file has been locked by another process, that's what I meant in my answer.

Comment: I understand. Another process does not need to know that a file is locked. Second process can't read/write the file simultaneously with the first process, so it suits me. I am just afraid that if the first process hangs for unknown reason all other processes can also hang. I don't know is such bad scenario is real or not? Maybe it is really reasonable to use SETLK to have a chance to stop waiting locked file. On the other hand any locked file is important and should not be locked for a long time. It will mean that all server hangs. Thanks!